# Swift 3: compress ImageView Vertically depending on its image height

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I am trying to create a table cell containing a primary image (`Content Mode = Aspect Fit`) and various other objects. I have pinned this imageView to the left and right margins and given it a height constraint of 600 to (hopefully) ensure the width of the provided device is utilized without distorting the photo.

However, my current implementation does not allow me to do so without forfeiting a decent amount of vertical real estate on the device; so my question is as follows:

**How does one trim any vertical excess space that is not being used for the photo?**

Please note that this is taking place in an xib table cell; so I will also need to properly configure the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat` function. (Unless this can be done some other way)

**EDIT: I changed the height constraint to <= 600, but the whitespace is still the same**

**My XIB can be seen below:**

---

[image: TableViewCell Xib]

---

**The resulting screenshot can be seen below with the lovely Emma Watson (Please note the unwanted white space):**

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to calculate the aspect and set the height manually. Only setting the contentMode will cause the image to scale inside the imageView but will not resize the imageView.

Here's how:

You will need a properties for your image view and height constraint, and a constant for your maximum height (`kMaxImageHeight`).

```
    guard let image = self.imageView.image else {
        return
    }

    let imageHeight = image.size.height;
    let aspect = imageHeight / image.size.width;

    // Constrain max height
    if (imageHeight > kMaxImageHeight && aspect > 1.0) {
        self.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = kMaxImageHeight;

    } else {
        // Otherwise calculate aspect and set height manually
        self.imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = aspect * self.imageView.frame.size.width;
    }
```

In a UIViewController you can simply put this code in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method but since you are using a UITableViewCell you can probably put it in a public method and call it whenever an image is set (including on cell resuse) and when the parent view controller calls `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Also, for cell height to work properly, best to make sure you have a constraint from your bottom-most view to the bottom of the superview (cell contentView) and use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.

Comment: Thank you so much, after playing around with the constraints (and setting the height constraint programmatically), i was able to get it to work